# How is having a wrapper class equals composition as described Joshua Bloch?

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I am reading the book effective java by Joshua Bloch. on the item 16 of "favor composition over inheritance", he gives an example of using HashSet and querying how many elements have been added since it was created(not to be confused with current size, which goes down when an element is removed). he provided the following code and here the getAddCount return 6, which I can understand. This should return 3 actually. (this is because HashSet's addAll method is implemented on top of its add method)

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class InstrumentedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    // The number of attempted element insertions
    private int addCount = 0;

    public InstrumentedHashSet() {
    }

    public InstrumentedHashSet(int initCap, float loadFactor) {
        super(initCap, loadFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        addCount++;
        return super.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        addCount += c.size();
        return super.addAll(c);
    }

    public int getAddCount() {
        return addCount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InstrumentedHashSet<String> s = new InstrumentedHashSet<String>();
        s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"));
        System.out.println(s.getAddCount());
    }
}
```

Now he explains a way to fix this, using wrapper classes (composition and forwarding). here is where I am having  hard time to understand.  he provides the following two classes

```
    public class ForwardingSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private final Set<E> s;

    public ForwardingSet(Set<E> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void clear() {
        s.clear();
    }

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return s.contains(o);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return s.isEmpty();
    }

    public int size() {
        return s.size();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return s.iterator();
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return s.add(e);
    }

    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return s.remove(o);
    }

    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return s.containsAll(c);
    }

    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        return s.addAll(c);
    }

    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return s.removeAll(c);
    }

    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return s.retainAll(c);
    }

    public Object[] toArray() {
        return s.toArray();
    }

    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return s.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return s.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return s.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s.toString();
    }
}
```

AND

```
import java.util.*;
    public class InstrumentedSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> {
        private int addCount = 0;

        public InstrumentedSet(Set<E> s) {
            super(s);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(E e) {
            addCount++;
            return super.add(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            addCount += c.size();
            return super.addAll(c);
        }

        public int getAddCount() {
            return addCount;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            InstrumentedSet<String> s = new InstrumentedSet<String>(
                    new HashSet<String>());
            s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"));
            System.out.println(s.getAddCount());
        }
    }
```

how this works? In the main method, I create an instance of HashSet and using addAll method, I add all the elements of list. but the HashSet invokes its addAll method (which in turn uses its add method), which should be the same as in the first in correct example and I should get value of 6, however this gives me 3.

Comment: Why should you be getting six? You are adding three elements to the 'InstrumentedSet', which is then appending its 'addCount' three times accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
public class InstrumentedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
```

you're adding directly to the `HashSet` because the `addAll()` is delegating to the super implementation

```
InstrumentedHashSet<String> s = new InstrumentedHashSet<String>();
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"));
System.out.println(s.getAddCount());
```

The `addAll()` internally calls `add()` which defers to your `@Override` implementation of `add()` because of polymorphism

```
@Override
public boolean add(E e) {
    addCount++;
    return super.add(e);
}
```

that increments the count and prints `6` (3 + 1 + 1 + 1).

In

```
public class InstrumentedSet<E> extends ForwardingSet<E> {
```

you are adding to

```
private final Set<E> s;
```

because the `addAll()` is delegating to it, so

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InstrumentedSet<String> s = new InstrumentedSet<String>(
                new HashSet<String>());
    s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop"));
    System.out.println(s.getAddCount());
}
```

and prints `3`. Here the `add()` is being called on the `Set<E> s`, not on your instance.

The conclusion is that if you are inheriting, you need to understand the side-effects. Do the `super` method calls invoke any other method calls internally? If so, you need to act appropriately.

Inheritance (start from bottom)

```
s.add() // s is your InstrumentedHashSet instance, because of polymorphism (inheritance), this adds to the count
this.add() // this is the internal call inside the HashSet#addAll()
super.addAll(...) // this calls the HashSet implementation of addAll which calls add() internally
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop")); // s is your InstrumentedHashSet instance
```

Composition

```
this.add() // this is the internal call to add() inside the Set implementation
s.addAll() // s is the Set<E> instance
super.addAll(...) // this calls the ForwardingSet implementation of addAll()
s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop")); // s is your InstrumentedSet instance
```

Comment: In first case returns 6 not 3.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Oh, because of `add()`

Comment: kindly paste the code and run it and see. you will get 6 for the first case.  That is explained in effective java by Joshua Bloch. It is because the addcount is incremented in both add and addAll method but addAll methods internally implements add method.

Comment: @user2708477 Yes, I missed the Overriden `add()`. See my edit.

Comment: can you explain how I am delegating `addAll` here? Even If I am calling `addAll()` on the `Set<E> s`, the internal implementation is `addAll` uses `add` method correct?

Comment: @user2708477 In the composition example, the `addAll()` calls `super.addAll()` which calls `s.addAll()`. That last `addAll()` is the one that calls `add()` internally. But internally means inside the `Set`, ie. not the one in your `ForwardingSet` class.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: even in the non-composition example (inheritance), I call super.addAll(). how is it then different? I am missing something, but unable to get what that is..

Comment: @user2708477 See if that helps. The inheritance case shows the effects of polymorphism. The composition shows the effects of delegation.

Comment: in inheritence, `super.addAll(...)` calls `hashSet adAll` implementation which in turn calls `hashSet add` implementation correct? or does it call add implementation of `InstrumentedHashSet`

Comment: @user2708477 Inside the `HashSet#addAll()` it calls `this.add()`, but as it turns out `this` refers to your instance of `InstrumentedHashSet` and so that `add()` (with count++) is executed.

Comment: `this` is the culprit I guess. Thank you for this detailed explanation. one tiny correction is that the very last line should be `s.addAll(Arrays.asList("Snap", "Crackle", "Pop")); // s is your InstrumentedSet instance`, ie should be `InstrumentedSet` instead of `InstrumentHashSet`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am sure this answer and comments will be useful for the first-time readers of effective Java by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 1):

`InstrumentedSet#getAddCount()` returns 6 because the size of the array (3) is added twice!

```
//InstrumentedSet
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    addCount += c.size(); //here
    return super.addAll(c); //and here!
}
```

`super.addAll(c);` calls the `add()` Method.

More detailed:

InstrumentedSet#addAll -> ForwardingSet#addAll (because of super.addAll) -> [HashSet#addAll()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) (because this is what you give it in the main) -> InstrumentedSet#add (because of polymorphism)

If you want a fix: remove `addCount += c.size();`

**`InstrumentedSet#addAll` returns 3 because it calls this:**

InstrumentedSet#addAll() (adds 3) -> ForwardingSet#addAll (because of super) -> HashSet#addAll (because forwardingset has a field of type HashSet) -> HashSet#add

Comment: InstrumentedSet returns 3. but InstrumentedHashSet return 6.I know why it is 6. I want to know how the wrapper class (ForwardingSet) actually helps here

Comment: what do mean by "helps here"

Comment: :did you try running this code? It returns 3 for InstrumentSet but returns 6 for InstrumentHashSet.

Comment: now it makes sense, Thanks for looking into it. however,you start with `InstrumentedSet#getAddCount() returns 6 because the size of the array (3) is added twice!` which should be `InstrumentedhasSet#getAddCount() returns 6 because the size of the array (3) is added twice!`