# Stats of HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

I wonder if there is a best way to get the aggregated statistics of objects in a `HashSet`. Is there any good approach rather than iterating the whole `Set`?

```
import java.lang.Thread.State;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Stats {

    static class Item {

        private State state;

        public State getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setState(State state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public Item(State state){
            this.state = state;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Stats.Item>();
        items.add(new Item(State.NEW));
        items.add(new Item(State.BLOCKED));
        items.add(new Item(State.BLOCKED));

        /*
         * printout here
         */
            // New=1
            // Blocked=2
    }
}
```

Comment: No, unless you customize Hashset implementation (Which will be almost equal to what you are doing now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,but you can write your own implementation of `Set` interface and in `add` method check item state and increments counters. Then you can retrive stats.

Comment: This might be an option. Do you have an idea on how to handle changes of the object states?

Comment: Each item should hold references to all sets it belongs to. After state change for example setter invocation, counters should be updated.

Comment: Ok, I will consider this if iteration turns out to be too costful when Items and States grows.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html might be idea

Answer (score 0):

No their isn't. However with a self-made implementation or a wrapper you might be able to calculate statistics while inserting into the hash set.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, doing something like this with a Set implementation is presented as an example in Bloch's Effective Java. Chosen precisely because if you want stats on the collection, you have to roll your own.

A search here reveals the reference I am thinking of, where he discusses composition over inheritance: [How is having a wrapper class equals composition as described Joshua Bloch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519192/how-is-having-a-wrapper-class-equals-composition-as-described-joshua-bloch)

I admit this is not strictly an answer to the question, but I think it adds to the conversation and shows an example of how (and why) to make your own instrumented classes for your own purposes.

Comment: Could you post a sample of this for your answer?

Comment: Alas, I only have a dead-tree edition, and it is not with me right now. I'll try to get the actual reference. It was on my mind because I just read it last night.